# Using Escape to close DataWindows

Tags: c#, wpf, catel

I have a DataWindow that has a UserControl. The VM for the UserControl and DataWindow is the same. In my constructor of the DataWindow I have :

```
public MyWindow(MyViewModel viewModel)
        : base(viewModel, DataWindowMode.OkCancel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        CanCloseUsingEscape = false;
    }
```

but having `CanCloseUsingEscape = false;` has no effect. the DataWindow still closes. To prevent the DataWindow from closing you would think to put this code in the code-behind of the DataWindow:

```
private void OnKeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == System.Windows.Input.Key.Escape)
            e.Handled = true;
    }
```

But this does not work. If I put it in the code-behind of the UserControl, then it works. Is this the expected behaviour?

Is there a way to globally switch it off and only switch it on on the DataWindows you would like to use this feature?

Comment: I have no idea what a `DataWindow` is, but try overriding the `OnPreviewKeyDown` method instead... that will be called before the `OnKeyDown` method.

Comment: The DataWindow is a Window from [Catel](http://catelproject.com/).

Comment: Have you tried debugging through the source to check the issue? See https://catelproject.atlassian.net/wiki/display/CTL/Stepping+through+the+code

Comment: @GeertvanHorrik I do not know if I'm doing this right, but I managed to get a breakpoint in on `DataWindow.OnKeyDown()`. `CanCloseUsingEscape` is false and `e.Key` is 'Escape'. I get to line `743: if (e.Key == Key.Escape && CanCloseUsingEscape)` and the result is false. then the code returns to `UIVisualizerService.ShowDialog()`, line 392: `window.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => result = showDialogMethodInfo.Invoke(window, null) as bool?)`. `result` is set to 'false'. Stepping again after this point takes me back to my application... with my window closed that was not suppose to close.

Comment: Strange. It should only close via the commands. Interested in doing a pull request with a fix?

Comment: Yeah, sure. I have never done one though, what do I need?

Comment: Create an issue here and we can discuss it there: https://catelproject.atlassian.net/secure/Dashboard.jspa

Comment: @GeertvanHorrik I have created the issue as requested